# How to change the style of CODialog

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, native

I am building a chat popup using
https://github.com/eaigner/CODialog

Here is the final result of the code:

[image]

All well but I can't change the default style, I tried the following code but it did nothing:

```
- (void)colorSubviewsOfView:(UIView *)view {

    // Get the subviews of the view
    NSArray *subviews = [view subviews];
    // Return if there are no subviews
    if ([subviews count] == 0) return; // COUNT CHECK LINE

    for (UIView *subview in subviews) {
        subview.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:118.0/255.0 blue:190.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [self colorSubviewsOfView:subview];
    }
}
```

I passed the self.dialog to the above function, the gray area is uiview inside uiscrollview that holds uilabels when writing and receiving chat messages

Is there any other way to color the title along side the buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the CODialog.m always return the components to the colors as in the picture so I override them to the color that I wanted and everything is OK